# How to position an element absolute to the window regardless of its DOM position?

Tags: css

I am creating a pop-up overlay modal and am having problems getting the positioning/scrolling working correctly.

I can set my modal to be `position:fixed` but then if the modal's height is too much, then the modal overflows off of the window and you cannot see the bottom of it.

If I set the modal to be `position:absolute` then the element becomes positioned relative to the closest ancestor with `position:relative`, correct? (or at least thats what it appears to do) Instead I want the modal to ALWAYS be relative to the window so that I can center it easily.

Is there a way to make the below `.modal` positioned relative to the window ( or  element) even if the element is nested deep inside the DOM like this:

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
<div>
    <div>
         <div ui-view>
              <div class=".modal"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: why not move the modal div under <body> tag?

Comment: You have two options: create (or move) the element at the root or ensure all parents are positioned as static. The former is obviously the easier way to go when you can use Javascript.

Comment: The problem is I am using AngularJS and UI-router, so my modal shows up inside of a `ui-view` directive which must be nested inside of parent views. Therefore, there is not possible way to place it in the body

Answer (score 0):

If you *insist* on having it in that same markup and nested in the same manner, your best bet is in JavaScript.

Here's some JS code that gives a good method of accomplishing what you asked for:

```
function ShowDivInCenter()
{
    try
    {
        divWidth = 100;
        divHeight = 100;
        divId = 'divLogin'; // id of the div that you want to show in center

        // Get the x and y coordinates of the center in output browser's window 
        var centerX, centerY;
        if (self.innerHeight)
        {
            centerX = self.innerWidth;
            centerY = self.innerHeight;
        }
        else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        {
            centerX = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            centerY = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        else if (document.body)
        {
            centerX = document.body.clientWidth;
            centerY = document.body.clientHeight;
        }

        var offsetLeft = (centerX - divWidth) / 2;
        var offsetTop = (centerY - divHeight) / 2;

        // The initial width and height of the div can be set in the
        // style sheet with display:none; divid is passed as an argument to // the function
        var ojbDiv = document.getElementById(divId);

        ojbDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        ojbDiv.style.top = offsetTop + 'px';
        ojbDiv.style.left = offsetLeft + 'px';
        ojbDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
    catch (e) {}
}
```

You can then call the function through any event, for example:

`<body onload='ShowDivInCenter();' onresize='ShowDivInCenter();'>`

if you want it to be dynamic.